# Custom error 404 en Apache con AWS ELB

Tags: ubuntu, apache, .htaccess, virtualhost

Acabo de instalar Apache y tengo problemas con la página 404.
Coloco en el virtual host: `ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?link1=404`
Pero no funciona.

Sale la página negra del navegador con el error `HTTP ERROR 502`

Nota: dicha página del navegador también sale sin que coloque `ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?link1=404` en los virtual host. No sé si tengo ese código 404 en otra parte de los vhost, porque en el `.htaccess` tango una referencia que antes sí me funcionaba en otro servidor (`RewriteRule ^404$ index.php?link1=404 [QSA]`). Aparentemente todo funciona del htaccess, menos eso.

**Me doy cuenta que en la IP sí funciona, pero en el dominio principal no, creo que es por el balanceador de carga.**

Comment: Qué te sale en los logs de apache? Tienes allowOverride en la configuración de apache?

Comment: Un error 502 suena mas a un error externo del servidor, se esta intentando conectar al servidor desde un servidor distinto? La IP es la misma de la maquina? Puedes compartir una captura de la pantalla?

Comment: Me doy cuenta que en la IP sí funciona, pero en el dominio principal no, creo que es por el balanceador de carga.